# Running PHP in Node.js

Tags: php, node.js, api, express

I am currently making a project using node.js and express. I have to use a map API. But the map API has PHP files containing all the logic. So how do i implement the PHP files in node.js. Please give a detailed explanation. Till now I haven't found any!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this PHP files directly in a nodejs program.
I assume these PHP files are a library of functions, usable by PHP code.
To use it by not reimplement it in node, you will have to expose this PHP API to make it callable by an external client (http or CLI by example).